# How can I get multiple different ProducerTemplate instances with Auto-Configured Producer Templates?

Tags: apache-camel

How can I get multiple different `ProducerTemplate` instances with Auto-Configured Producer Templates? If I use the auto configured `ProducerTemplate`, how can I get multiple different `ProducerTemplate` instances?

For example, I need to use `producertemplate` to send different exchanges to different endpoints. In this case, do I need different producer template instances? If so, how can I do that?

> Auto-Configured Consumer and Producer Templates
>   Camel auto-configuration provides pre-configured ConsumerTemplate and ProducerTemplate instances. You can simply inject them into your Spring-managed beans:

```
@Component
public class InvoiceProcessor {    
  @Autowired
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;
  public void processNextInvoice() {
    Invoice invoice = consumerTemplate.receiveBody("jms:invoices", Invoice.class);
    ...
    producerTemplate.sendBody("netty-http:http://invoicing.com/received/" + invoice.id());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You **do not need** different `ProducerTemplate`s just to send messages to different endpoints. However, it can be convenient.

**Send messages to whatever endpoint**

Use the `send*` (InOnly) and `request*` (InOut) methods of [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) that take the target endpoint URI as first argument.

```
template.sendBody("activemq:MyQueue", "<hello>world!</hello>");
template.requestBody("direct:MyEndpoint", "<hello>world!</hello>");
```

**Inject multiple ProducerTemplates with Camel Annotation**

See [Camel docs about this](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html) for details.

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "activemq:MyQueue")
protected ProducerTemplate myQueueProducer;
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:MyEndpoint")
protected ProducerTemplate myEndpointProducer;
```

**Autowire multiple ProducerTemplates (Spring)**

Since you want multiple instances of the same type, you have to inject them by name with the `@Qualifier` annotation. It would be better to configure the default endpoint in your Spring Bean configuration, I just added the `setDefaultEndpointUri` calls to show how to do it.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myQueueProducer")
protected ProducerTemplate myQueueProducer;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myEndpointProducer")
protected ProducerTemplate myEndpointProducer;
...
myQueueProducer.setDefaultEndpointUri("activemq:MyQueue")
myEndpointProducer.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:MyEndpoint")
```